# jquery popup window onload

Tags: jquery, popup

I want to show a pop up on page load and had a checkbox field in that popup, i want that page should only be visible if the checkbox is checked. The problem is that it works well on click function, but not able to get it work on checkbox. This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

    //if close button is clicked
      if ($('.window .close').attr('checked')==true){
    function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
        }};     

        //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
        });     

      });

   </script>


    <div style="font-size: 10px; color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">lorem ipsum</div>

     <div id="boxes">
<div style="top: 199.5px; left: 551.5px; display: none;" id="dialog" class="window">
Simple Modal Window | 
<input type="checkbox" class="close">
</div>
<!-- Mask to cover the whole screen -->
<div style="width: 1478px; height: 602px; display: none; opacity: 0.8;" id="mask">    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post concise code examples as this will help those who are answering your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading this [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/home). This is awesome and you can open a pop up and have checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

not able to understand your question completely..so you need to make it like if user clicks the checkbox the mask disappears and page shows up?

does your  show up on top of the mask because there's no detail on the z-index of the div..if it does alter the code as

```
$('#mask, .close').click(function () { 
   .
   .
```

to get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

You should change your codes as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

var id = '#dialog';

//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

//transition effect     
$('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
$('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

//Get the window height and width
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();

//Set the popup window to center
$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
$(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

//transition effect
$(id).fadeIn(2000);     

//if close checbox is checked
  if ($('.window .close').attr('checked')==false){

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();

  }; 

  //if close checkbox is clicked
  $('.window .close').click(function(){

      if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
      }

  });      

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

});
```

You should add checkbox attribute "checked".

```
<input type="checkbox" class="close" checked="checked">
```

Comment: That wont work -> how is `if ($('.window .close').attr('checked')==true){` going to ever work its only evaluated onDomReady

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are looking for an event to be fired when the checkbox is checked?

if so, the function there should be in the click event of the checkbox

```
    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function(){
      if ($(this).attr('checked')==true)
      {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your close function is not valid JavaScript :

```
 //if close button is clicked
 if ($('.window .close').attr('checked')==true){
    function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
 }};
```

You could removed both click events and replace with a single code block ->

```
$('#dialog .close, #mask').click(function(e){ //listen for clicks on the mask and close checkbox
    $('#mask').hide();   // hide the mask
    $('#dialog').hide(); // hide the dialog div
});
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/4Mpb3/2/